# ParserError: Expected ';' but got 'event' -- solidity 0.8 address payable(msg.sender)

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, solidity, pragma

I don't know why I still get this error, I have already changed this `address payable(msg.sender)` to line 81 (I bold the line below) according to solidity 0.8 update,  but it still gives an error. Can anyone assist, please?

I have indicated line 81 on this code below.

*CONSOLE ERROR*

### **ParserError: Expected ';' but got 'event'

|
50 |     event ImageCreated(
|     ^^^^^**

```
pragma solidity 0.8.12;

contract GistPin {
    string public name = "GistPin";
    uint256 public videoCount = 0;
    uint256 public imageCount = 0;
    mapping(uint256 => Image) public images;
    mapping(uint256 => Video) public videos;

    struct Image {
        uint256 id;
        string hash;
        string description;
        uint256 tipAmount;
        address payable author;
    }

    struct Video {
        uint256 id;
        string hash;
        string title;
        address author;
    }

    event VideoUploaded(
        uint256 id,
        string hash,
        string title,
        string description,
        address author
    );

    constructor() public {
        name = "GistPin";
    }

    function uploadVideo(
        string memory _videoHash,
        string memory _title,
        string memory _description
    ) public {
        // Make sure the video hash exists
        require(bytes(_videoHash).length > 0);
        // Make sure video title exists
        require(bytes(_title).length > 0);
        // Make sure video description exists
        require(bytes(_description).length > 0);
        // Make sure uploader address exists
        require(msg.sender != address(0));

        // Increment video id
        videoCount++;

        // Add video to the contract
        videos[videoCount] = Video(videoCount, _videoHash, _title, msg.sender);
        // Trigger an event
        emit VideoUploaded(
            videoCount,
            _videoHash,
            _title,
            _description,
            msg.sender
        );
    }

    event ImageCreated(
        uint256 id,
        string hash,
        string description,
        uint256 tipAmount,
        address payable author
    );

    event ImageTipped(
        uint256 id,
        string hash,
        string description,
        uint256 tipAmount,
        **address payable(msg.sender)**     // ERROR LINE 81
    );

    function uploadImage(string memory _imgHash, string memory _description) public {
    // Make sure the image hash exists
    require(bytes(_imgHash).length > 0);
    // Make sure image description exists
    require(bytes(_description).length > 0);
    // Make sure uploader address exists
    require(msg.sender!=address(0x0));

     // Increment image id
    imageCount ++;

    // Add Image to the contract
    images[imageCount] = Image(imageCount, _imgHash, _description, 0, msg.sender);
    // Trigger an event
    emit ImageCreated(imageCount, _imgHash, _description, 0, msg.sender);
  }

  function tipImageOwner(uint _id) public payable {
    // Make sure the id is valid
    require(_id > 0 && _id <= imageCount);
    // Fetch the image
    Image memory _image = images[_id];
    // Fetch the author
    address payable _author = _image.author;
    // Pay the author by sending them Ether
    address(_author).transfer(msg.value);
    // Increment the tip amount
    _image.tipAmount = _image.tipAmount + msg.value;
    // Update the image
    images[_id] = _image;
    // Trigger an event
    emit ImageTipped(_id, _image.hash, _image.description, _image.tipAmount, _author);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

can you add what the exact error your getting from the console

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT 
pragma solidity 0.8.12;

contract GistPin {
  string public name = "GistPin";
  uint256 public videoCount = 0;
  uint256 public imageCount = 0;
  mapping(uint256 => Image) public images;
  mapping(uint256 => Video) public videos;

  struct Image {
    uint256 id;
    string hash;
    string description;
    uint256 tipAmount;
    address payable author;
  }

  struct Video {
    uint256 id;
    string hash;
    string title;
    address author;
  }

  event VideoUploaded(
    uint256 id,
    string hash,
    string title,
    string description,
    address author
  );

  constructor() {
    name = "GistPin";
  }

  function uploadVideo(
    string memory _videoHash,
    string memory _title,
    string memory _description
  ) public {
    // Make sure the video hash exists
    require(bytes(_videoHash).length > 0);
    // Make sure video title exists
    require(bytes(_title).length > 0);
    // Make sure video description exists
    require(bytes(_description).length > 0);
    // Make sure uploader address exists
    require(msg.sender != address(0));

    // Increment video id
    videoCount++;

    // Add video to the contract
    videos[videoCount] = Video(videoCount, _videoHash, _title, msg.sender);
    // Trigger an event
    emit VideoUploaded(
        videoCount,
        _videoHash,
        _title,
        _description,
        msg.sender
    );
  }

  event ImageCreated(
    uint256 id,
    string hash,
    string description,
    uint256 tipAmount,
    address payable author
  );

  event ImageTipped(
    uint256 id,
    string hash,
    string description,
    uint256 tipAmount,
    // Declare the variable 
    address payable myAddress
  );

   function uploadImage(string memory _imgHash, string memory _description) public {
    // Make sure the image hash exists
    require(bytes(_imgHash).length > 0);
    // Make sure image description exists
    require(bytes(_description).length > 0);
    // Make sure uploader address exists
    require(msg.sender!=address(0x0));

    // Increment image id
    imageCount ++;

    // Add Image to the contract

    images[imageCount] = Image(imageCount, _imgHash, _description, 0, payable(msg.sender));
    // Trigger an event

    emit ImageCreated(imageCount, _imgHash, _description, 0, payable(msg.sender));
  }

function tipImageOwner(uint _id) public payable {
    // Make sure the id is valid
    require(_id > 0 && _id <= imageCount);
    // Fetch the image
    Image memory _image = images[_id];
    // Fetch the author
    address payable _author = _image.author;
    // Pay the author by sending them Ether
    _author.transfer(msg.value);
    // Increment the tip amount
    _image.tipAmount = _image.tipAmount + msg.value;
    // Update the image
    images[_id] = _image;
    // Trigger an event
    emit ImageTipped(_id, _image.hash, _image.description, _image.tipAmount, payable(_author));
 }

}
```

You must declare a variable into `ImageTipped event` in this way : `address payable myAddress`. And each time you call the event with emit you will have to pass it the msg.sender in this way: `payable(msg.sender)`.
For more information see line: **81** and **118** in my code.

Comment: Thanks so much. it works. if you dont mind I will like to add you on telegram in regards to the project I am working on.

Comment: Yeah no problem, what is your telegram username?

Comment: my telegrm " gmertonline

Comment: my telegrm " gmertonline

Comment: i dont see you online ... kindly get back to me.